# Why am I getting this error when trying to open a file with DDD?

Tags: c, debugging, ddd-debugger

**Debugger: DDD.**

**64-bit Ubuntu Precise Pangolin system.**

Whenever I try to open a very simple C program in ddd I get the following error:

```
Warning: This program is an suid-root program or is being run by the root user.
The full text of the error or warning message cannot be safely formatted
in this environment. You may get a more descriptive message by running the
program as a non-root user or by removing the suid bit on the executable.
Warning: Cannot convert string "%s" to type %s
Warning: Could not load font "-*-lucidatypewriter-medium-*-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*", using font "fixed" instead
Warning: Could not load font "-*-lucidatypewriter-medium-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*", using font "fixed" instead
Warning: Could not load font "-*-lucidatypewriter-bold-*-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*", using font "fixed" instead
Warning: XmStringGetNextComponent: unknown type 26933216

Warning: XmStringGetNextComponent: unknown type 26664160

Warning: XmStringGetNextComponent: unknown type 26721536

Warning: XmStringGetNextComponent: unknown type 27713552

Warning: XmStringGetNextComponent: unknown type 26719456

Warning: XmStringGetNextComponent: unknown type 26994752

Warning: XmStringGetNextComponent: unknown type 27761616
```

Also, ddd opens up fine after all these errors get displayed on the terminal, but without the source file I want to debug. I can't find an solution to this online! Thanks.

EDIT:

I get the above error when running as root. I get the following when running as a normal user:

```
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-r-*-*-*-100-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-lucidatypewriter-medium-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-lucidatypewriter-bold-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-bold-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-*-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-bold-*-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-bold-r-*-*-*-180-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-symbol-*-*-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-adobe-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Could not load font "-*-lucidatypewriter-medium-*-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*", using font "fixed" instead
Warning: Could not load font "-*-lucidatypewriter-medium-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*", using font "fixed" instead
Warning: Could not load font "-*-lucidatypewriter-bold-*-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*", using font "fixed" instead
Warning: XmStringGetNextComponent: unknown type 27122480

Warning: XmStringGetNextComponent: unknown type 27125120

Warning: XmStringGetNextComponent: unknown type 27119296

Warning: XmStringGetNextComponent: unknown type 27109856

Warning: XmStringGetNextComponent: unknown type 27150160

Warning: XmStringGetNextComponent: unknown type 27132208
```

Comment: What command are you using to start DDD?

Comment: I'm using the following: `ddd prac1.c &`.

Comment: ...and the output of `whoami`? (since it looks like you try to run ddd as root which is probably not what you want)

Comment: I'm running as root. I tried running as a normal user but I get the same problem, though not the suid-bit part.

Comment: You don't run `ddd` on the source, try `ddd a.out` (or whatever you called your executable).

Comment: I tried running it on my executable, but I still get the exact same error.

Comment: see http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?30270 (and yes, I get the same printout)

Comment: Hum. That bug was reported two years ago, is there a way to change DDD's config files to allow UTF-8? I don't know much about changing config files. And does that mean my code is using UTF-8 characters?

Comment: Does this error mean I'm using UTF-8 characters on my code?

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured it out with the help of @Fredrik.

UTF-8 incompatibility seems to be a long-standing bug in ddd. Many people have reported it but no one seems to have fixed it yet.

The reason my code wasn't displaying in ddd was because I wasn't using the `-g` option when compiling.